# Detect and crop on biggest object or subject shape from image - PHP & JS only

Tags: javascript, php, imagemagick, gd

I have an image with multiple plans.
I want to crop it focused on the biggest object from the photo (generaly a paper sheet).

First I decided to apply a Black and White filter, then reverse it, this helps to crop the photo on easy setups (meaning the object is on a table without anything else in the photo.)

```
 1. imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE); 
 2. imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -1000); 
 3. imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
 4. imagejpeg($im, "B&W.jpg");
```

Which gave me the following photo :

[Result of B&W.jpg - Black and White processing and reverse colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVAqc.png)

What i thaught would work was the GD or Imagemagic solutions :

```
$cropped = imagecropauto($im , IMG_CROP_WHITE);
$cropped = imagecropauto($im , IMG_CROP_BLACK);
```

OR

```
$im->trimImage(0);
```

But i doesn't work with multiple shapes.

I started to look for a solution to crop the photo based on shapes (rectangular).

And that's where I'm at.

I want to autocrop the photo on the biggest shape of the photo. Any ideas ?

Edit: @fmw42 Hello,

So here is what i'm at :

`$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('test.jpg');`
[An exemple of image](https://prnt.sc/JYW2s0apn2ey)

```
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -1000);
imagejpeg($im, "test_B&W.jpg");
```

[Black and white image - test_B&W.jpg](https://prnt.sc/qPlM9n32HgQD)

```
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
imagejpeg($im, "test_B&W_reversed.jpg");
```

[Black and white image - test_B&W.jpg](https://prnt.sc/UvVqvrKE9vbP)

Here the B&W is I think more exploitable.

I then use :

```
$cropped = imagecropauto($im , IMG_CROP_WHITE);
if ($cropped !== false) { 
    imagedestroy($im);  
    $im = $cropped;     
}
imagejpeg($im, "test_B&W_cropped.jpg");
```

[Black and white image cropped - test_B&W_cropped.jpg](https://prnt.sc/OmwpIlXplDcX)

I then tried using GD and the IMG_CROP_WHITE, IMG_CROP_BLACK, IMG_CROP_DEFAULT without luck.

And

```
$imagick = new \Imagick(realpath("./test_B_W_cropped.jpg"));
$imagick ->trimImage(-1);
$imagick ->setImageBackgroundColor(new \ImagickPixel('transparent'));
header("Content-Type: image/" . $imagick ->getImageFormat());
echo $imagick ;
```

[output of trim](https://prnt.sc/NhfBI7TYYdLx)

And that's it, I'm stuck.

- The wanted result are either :

Get the coordinates and size of the square shape to then crop with specific pixels points.
OR
Crop directly based on biggest "square" shape from photo.

[Like : (auto detect this shape)](https://prnt.sc/v50EgqzfB14Q)

[And the crop and display FINAL RESULT](https://prnt.sc/PO4hO67tv4B5)

Comment: It would help to see the original before processing. See Imagemagick -connected-components

Comment: Hello @fmw42 just updated with more complete example. Saw  -connected-components but the thing is that i can't use commande line (at this time ? May have permission to do so after. But first need to explore all options)

Comment: Best bet would be to call the command line from PHP exec(). Then you could use connected components and get the rotated rectangle. See https://imagemagick.org/script/convex-hull.php

Comment: Hello, 

Had help on the Imagemagick github 

They recommanded me to used 

-canny 
&
-hough-lines 

That's a huge improvement, and then used connected-components if multiple paper on photo. 

Currently I still have issues with multiple hough-lines. 

Yes definitely; I will use exec()